# How to access value of __nssingleobjectarrayi in the following code

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, alamofire

I parsed a json and got a JSON Dictionary.

```
{
data =     (
            {
        bio = "<null>";
        bookmarked = 35;
        id = 22;
        "last_seen" =             {
            date = "2017-03-30 14:00:01";
            timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
            "timezone_type" = 3;
        };
        name = "Alex";
        username = "Alex";
    }
);}
```

I am trying to access username and date.
I tried it doing

```
let name = userData.value(forKeyPath: "data.username")
print(username)
```

By printing this, I am getting a __NSSingleObjectArrayI with the username.

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6080000120b0>(
Alex
)
)
```

How do I access that and display at other places? Basically extract the "Alex" from that as a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value(forKeyPath` applied to an array containing dictionaries returns an array – as revealed in the output. You need to get the first item of the array

```
let names = userData.value(forKeyPath: "data.username")
if !names.isEmpty { print(names[0]) }
```

However the usual way to get the name is

```
if let data = userDatavalue["data") as? [[String:Any]], !data.isEmpty,
   let username = data[0]["username"] as? String {
      print(username)
}
```

Comment: What if I want to access multiple values from the dictionary and they are not all from the same data type? Let's say they can be either Double or String.

Comment: You have to conditionally downcast (`as? Double`, `as? Int`) all types separately.