# How to get value of a NSSingleObjectArrayI

Tags: swift, api

```
func responseDataHandler(data: NSDictionary) {
        let temperature_c = data.value(forKeyPath: "data.current_condition.temp_C")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.Temperature.text = temperature_c as? String
        }

    }
```

I have the above code where I am accessing a weather API which returns data in the form of an NSDictionary to this function. I need to access the value in temperature_c which when I try to print it, it says that it is: Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600002147fd0>(
25
)
). Temperature is the outlet for label on my storyboard which I want to take on the value of 25 however as written now, it doesn't work and I have tried everything to try and access the value in the Single Object Array but nothing is working. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112592/how-to-access-value-of-nssingleobjectarrayi-in-the-following-code) stack overflow question that was similar but it doesn't work for my situation because I keep getting the error that temperature_c is of type any and doesn't have subscripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't cast to String an array, you should try to convert it to `[String]`.  So could change your code to:

```
self.Temperature.text = (temperature_c as? [String])?.first ?? "Not available"
```

Let's go step by step:

1. `temperature_c as? [String]` tries to convert the `NSDictionary` to a String array which is the expectable type.
2. Since the previous step may return `nil` we have to use optional chaining `?`. If we got a valid array using `first` return the the arrays first element.
3. Since both previous steps can return `nil` we can use nil coalescing operator to return a default value. In this case I use "Not available" but you can set any value.

You could write it in a more verbose way like this:

```
     var text2Display2 = "Not available"
     if let theArray = temperature_c as? [String] {
        if let element = theArray.first {
           text2Display2 = element
        }
     }
     self.Temperature.text = text2Display2
```

Comment: That worked! I'm not sure at all why though could you explain? Particularly the "Not available" part

Comment: The "Not available" is just a random text I set to display in case something goes wrong decoding the data, you can set a blank string, etc. I edited the answer to explain what I did. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I REALLY appreciate this. Swift has been a rough road trying to learn but people like you who help out random strangers on the internet have really made it a lot better!

Comment: Working with dictionaries is slow and you have to write many defensive code to check that that the data fetched is ok. Nowadays is better to use strong types and take advantage of JSON Decoder. You can use a site like https://app.quicktype.io to generate Swift code that represents the json response. I'll add a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449278/cant-access-json-data-from-weather-api to help you with this.

Comment: The last thing that I need to do is get the image out of the API however this is nested within a further layer of JSON so the above code breaks because for some reason its now a 2D NSSingleObjectArrayI so the initial cast fails and the value ends up as "Not Available". I've tried tinkering with the code from the answer above but nothing seems to be working. Is this even the correct way to assign this URL value to an ImageView? I figured I would need the url no matter what method I did which is why I'm just trying to get it out right now but am certianly open to suggestions